# libGDX: same texture with shaders, different textures without

Tags: libgdx, textures, shader

my name ist Tom (Ger) and i am developing a small `3D` game with libGDX.

when i am using a Model, ModelInstance with a ModelBatch and the Environment, i can render different ModelInstances (with different Models) with there right textures.

But i need to use a shader for some wobble effects.

But when i use a shader everything works finde, except for the textures. there are the same for every ModelInscance i want to render.

i guess there is a texture binding problem. I load my Models this way:

```
assets = new AssetManager();
assets.load("blob.g3db", Model.class);
```

and fetch them with a simple:

```
public static Model getModel(String name) {
    return assets.get(name + ".g3db", Model.class);
}
```

So i guess the assetsManager is loading the textures as well (cause it works without the shader).

My Question is:
How can i render differend `3D` Objects with a Shader with there correct Textures?

Thanks in Advance...
Tom

Answer (score 0):

The `Model`s and the `ModelInstance`s have a `Material`, where you can set a `Texture`, `Color` and other things to it.
So if 2 `ModelInstance`s share the same `Model` you can set different `Material`s to their `ModelInstance`s. By doing this you have different `Texture`s. The `DefaultShader` implementation takes care about them. If you create your own `Shader` you need to take care about them.
Important: It does not work **without** `Shader`, cause you always render with `Shader`. You don't set the `Shader` manually, but libgdx uses `DefaultShader` by default.
I suggest you read some of [Xoppas tutorials](http://blog.xoppa.com/).